# Can I use spark hivecontext over cassandra database?

Tags: cassandra, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I am new to these technologies, I have managed to setup cassandra & spark integration successfuly. Currently we are using spark sqlContext, but can I use hiveContext for same database as HiveQL parser is more feature rich & complete, as mentioned in their documentation [here](https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.3.0/sql-programming-guide.html#starting-point-sqlcontext)

Comment: I think you can. Please refer the below link once. http://www.russellspitzer.com/2015/01/10/CassandraRdd-HiveQL/                            Let me know, if this is not what you ve asked for.

Comment: Thanks for the article link. In my case it worked, I just needed to append keyspace before all tablenames thats it. like
select * from mykeyspace.mytablename;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can. Please refer the below link once. russellspitzer.com/2015/01/10/CassandraRdd-HiveQL Let me know, if this is not what you ve asked for.